# Acquiring GPS data from mobile browser

Tags: browser, background, refresh

I'm working on a project where I'm supposed to get the GPS location coordinates from a delivery man and send it to a server. I've searched for a script that allows me to do so, and I'm sending data every 5 seconds. The problem is that if I lock the phone (I tried it on safari/iphone and chrome/android phones) the browser stops refreshing and I can't get data anymore. And if i do not lock the phone, the screen, being turned on, will drain my battery...

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why do you have to run the script on your phone?

Comment: @syntonym my question is that how to be able to refresh the browser while it's running in background. I'm running this script on my phone, because the delivery man will be holding a **phone with a GPS sensor**, and will send us the data by just opening a given URL where the browser refreshes every 5 seconds to acquire his new position.
_(I'm using the GET php function to acquire data from URL request...)_

Comment: Just to check if my understanding is correct: The phone that the delivery man is holding is *not* the phone that runs the script?

Comment: @syntonym, No it is! I mean, if his phone gets locked, he'll not be able to send me any more data, and I won't be able to track him

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do that. Browsers are designed to be used interactively, so if it is not used it will not process to save on ressources. [This apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070) seems to indicate something in the direction you wan't, but I don't know if that will suit your case.

Instead you should write an app that works that way. [Android on services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) seems to exactly match what you are looking for:

> A Service is an application component representing [...] an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user